# calc() to create a canvas which scales in accordance to a device aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, css-calc

I'm trying to create a canvas which is sized based on a ratio depending on the device. I have a final image I need to display with the following dimensions:

```
img {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 80vh;
}
```

This image is created from a canvas. I need to size this canvas in accordance to the expected ratio.  I thought I could do the following by calculating the (inverse) aspect ratio and storing that as a variable:

```
:root {
    --device-ratio: calc(80vh / 100vw);
}
.someCanvas {
    width: 50vw;
    height: calc(var(--device-ratio) * 50vw);
}
```

In theory this was what I expected to need to do. But the problem is that with `/` and `*` in `calc()`, they require [at least one of the values to be a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()#syntax) and specifically for `/`, the right value must be a number.

How should I be doing this without JavaScript? The ratio of the height to width of this image will be different based on each device, but that's okay. I'm looking to keep it consistent *within* the usage from a single device.

EDIT: I can calculate the ratio out in reference to the desired final dimensions, but that would mean I'd need to do that for every element's width and height. If I can somehow do it this way, I can declare widths as necessary and all I need to do is scale the height by `--device-ratio`. If not, I'll need to calculate the ratio out for every element manually. Certainly possible, just time consuming.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if the image size is width 100vw and height 80vh and you want the canvas with the same ratio, you have 50vw as the with so it's half of the image so the height would be 40vh, no need to use calc, that will have the same ratio as the image. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @arieljuod Sorry yes, I should have included that in the question. I can certainly use this ratio, but I was wondering if this dependence is at all possible. Because then for any element, I can declare a width and for the height, I just need to scale the width by `--device-ratio`. If not, for every element I will need to determine the ratio from the main element and then use that ratio for the height. It's not a difficult process, just more time consuming.